# How to create new brushes for photoshop?

Tags: photoshop

I started downloading few brush presets. Now I wonder, how to make new photoshop brush presets(like the shape of brush, etc.)

Comment: I believe the "special" brushes (those that aren't essentially rubber-stamps) are hard-coded by Adobe. I'm not aware of how it's possible (if at all) to do that from external code. However making the rubber-stamp brushes is easy ("Edit > Define Brush").

Comment: @Dai thanks for your help, I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following -
1. Design a brush on a normal canvas.
2. Select the image ( Ctrl + A ) and goto Edit --> Define Brush Preset.
3. Done.

Hope it helped

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer!

Answer (score 3):

Installing Photoshop brushes step by step:

1. Search for a basic brush set and find one you like on an internet (a few good sites – DevianArt, Creative Market, Design Cuts)
2. Download the .ZIP file to your computer
3. Use a ZIP Extractor to open the file and make sure there is a ".abr" file in the folder (it’s the only one that matters for you)
4. Open up the Photoshop in order to install your brushes
5. Click on the Brush tool, to bring up the brush bar on the top of the screen
6. Click on the small downward arrow in the brush bar which opens up the Brushes Preset Menu.
7. Click on the gear symbol, then "Load Brushes” and find the brushes you have just downloaded (these are in the .apr file)
8. Double-click on the .apr file to install your brushes (This will automatically add your brushes to your preset menu)